# numeric fields turning into "char" while using stringsAsFactor = F

Tags: r

I am trying to import a few csv files from a specific folder:

```
setwd("C://Users//XYZ//Test")

filelist = list.files(pattern = ".*.csv")

datalist = lapply(filelist, FUN=read.delim, sep = ',', header=TRUE,
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

for (i in 1:length(datalist)){
    datalist[[i]]<-cbind(datalist[[i]],filelist[i])
}

Data = do.call("rbind", datalist)
```

After I use the above code, a few columns are type `character`, despite containing numbers. If I don't use `stringsAsFactor = F` then the fields read as `factor` which turns into missing values when I use `as.numeric(as.character())` later on.

Is there any solution so that I can keep some fields as `numeric`? The fields that I want to be as `numeric` look like this:

```
Price.Plan     Feature.Charges

$180.00        $6,307.56    
$180.00        $5,431.25
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have those `$`  and `,` in the input data.  That will force the data to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$`, `,` are not considered `numeric`, so while using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `read.delim`, it assigns the column type as `character`.  To change that, remove the `$`, `,` with `gsub`, convert to `numeric` and assign it to the particular columns

```
df <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("[$,]", "", x)))
```

Comment: it gives some error while applying code : df<-mutate(df,TotalPrice=rowSums(df[,c(2,3)],na.rm =TRUE)), error i get "Error is rowSums(df[, c(2,3)], na.rm = TRUE) : 
  'x' must be numeric"

Comment: @SaibalDutta  are you sure the columns are `numeric` check the `str(df)`.  It could be that you have more characters other than $ or ,

Comment: @SaibalDutta  If it is numeric, it would work fine `df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10);
 df %>% mutate(TotalPrice = rowSums(df[1:2]))`

Comment: its all numeric, it does not have any other characters

Comment: @SaibalDutta  Have you checked the `str(df)` after the removal using the code above/  If it is numeric, it should work as the example I showed is all numeric and is working

Comment: if I check structure it shows "num", however when I check class using code: sapply(df,class) it shows "list", before removing $ it was "character", can this be a reason?

Comment: now i have cracked it, i just made a small change in your formula and everything now works fine, I am now using this code: df$column<-as.numeric(lapply(df$column, function(x) gsub('[$,]","",x))) thanks for your help, much appreciate

Comment: I am not sure about the syntax based on the comments and code you showed.  I am guessing that you have a column that is a `list` instead of a vector